# Links broken on everywhere except internet browsers

Tags: hyperlink

I did some stupid things and ended up deleting AppData. Since then, no links to websites have worked on any program other than internet browsers. These are things like "forgot password" links in game clients and links to websites in pdf documents. Can anyone help?

Windows 7 64 bit OS

**Note**: If I set my default browser to IE it works, but not when I set it to Chrome

Comment: Could it be as simple as re-setting your default browser in the control panel?

Comment: Try re-installing chrome

Comment: Chrome is partly installed in Appdata. You deleted Appdata. Now Chrome doesn't work. How is this even a question?